# How to migrate coredata into Action extension in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, core-data, safari-extension, core-data-migration

I am new to core data, I've used [this](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions/?doing_wp_cron=1490856040.1439070701599121093750) to perform certain steps but from iOS 10 below methods are created by defaults,

```
- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
// The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
@synchronized (self) {
    if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
        _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"namanCoreData"];
        [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                abort();
            }
        }];
    }
}

return _persistentContainer;}
```

any idea/link/suggestion about how to use core data into  Action Extension? Help . . .

Comment: What problem(s) do you have when attempting to use this code in your extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing.  Just after the `initWithName` and before the `loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler` create a `NSPersistent​Store​Description` object, set its URL and then set the `_persistentContainer`'s `persistent​Store​Descriptions` property to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful :

[NSPersistentContainer uses a new class NSPersistentStoreDescription to describe the configuration information to pass to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator when adding a persistent store. NSPersistentStoreDescription defaults to an NSSQLiteStoreType with automatic light weight migration enabled.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html)

So, in iOS10, you just need to

- select xcdatamodeld file
- Editor > Add Model Version...
- switch to new version. Modify what you want

Done ~